# How to join windows 2012 to windows 2016 AD domain

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have a lab environment with a Win Server 2016 that serves as a AD DC and I have a Win Server 2012 that I'm attempting to join to the domain. Requesting assistance to see what I'm doing wrong.

Win 2016 Server Config:

1. Installed AD DC and DNS role
2. Domain name red_domain.com
3. Static address configured as 192.168.1.111
4. Preferred DNS set to 192.168.1.111 (not sure of this is right)
5. Alternate DNS is 8.8.8.8
6. Confirmed can ping win server 2012

Win Server 2012 Config:

1. Static address configured as 192.168.1.112
2. Preferred DNS set to 192.168.1.111
3. Alternate DNS 8.8.8.8
4. Confirmed can ping Win 2016 Server
5. Getting DNS error joining to domain

Error I'm getting is displayed below:

[image]

EDIT:
Below is the result of the nslookup:

[image]

Comment: It's right there in the screen shot. That record is not being returned from the query. Use nslookup.

Comment: You've told us the domain name in your question, why are you blocking it out in your image? How are we to know if you're using the right domain name in your join request if you block it out? Additionally, stop using 8.8.8.8 for secondary DNS on both servers.

Comment: @joeqwerty ok got it. My domain is flackbox.com. I removed 8.8.8.8 as the secondary DNS from my win server 2012. Then, on server 2012, I performed an nslookup flackbox.com and I have posted an edit to the post to show results. The IP doesn't seem right. Could you advise?

Comment: @GregAskew I have edited the post to include the results of the nslookup. It appears to be displaying wrong IP. What am I missing to remediate?

Comment: Your AD Domain is **red_domain.com**. That's the domain you should be joining, not flackbox.com.

Comment: @joeqwerty nice...